# How to access a folder over SSH between 2 Windows 10 computers

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, bash, ssh, samba

I'd like to use bash in windows 10 to establish SSH tunnel and mount remote folder to a local one.

Until now I've been using Ubuntu in VirtualBox on each Windows machine, run sshfs server and then shared the folders with hosts as samba network shares. I'm looking to simplify this. Ideally with the use of bash in windows 10.

I've also tried putty with loopback adapter on Windows but never managed to have it all working. Basic user here.

Comment: Can you successfully use SSH to connect from one Ubuntu to the other Ubuntu instance? In that case, you can also run `sshfs`.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) version 2 (windows 10 build 2004). To mount the remote location I used sshfs that needs FUSE to work. But fuse does not work on WSL1.

So now in Ubuntu bash on WSL2 on Windows 10 I can run:

```
sudo sshfs thomas@192.168.0.10:/ /home/thomas/Farone2  -o allow_other -o port=222 -o reconnect -o identityfile=/home/thomas/.ssh/id_rsa
```

on WSL1 I was getting errors:

```
fuse: device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first

thomas@ThomasLondon:~$ modprobe fuse modprobe: FATAL: Module fuse not
found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-18362-Microsoft
```

**sshfs command works in Ubuntu bash in WSL2 on Windows 10 as expected**

Now I have mapped the remote location from another Windows 10 PC via SSH and Windows 10 works with the files the same way as if they were stored locally. There is WSL1 running on the remote computer with SSH service running.

I automated this using Windows task scheduler that runs the script to mount the remote location automatically on start or WorkStationUnlock etc.

If this is to be run automatically you need to use the keyfile option to authenticate using keys so the password is not needed to access the remote PC.

You'll also need to edit the sudoers file in Ubuntu so the script that you will run to mount the folder with sudo won't be requiring password.

more on running bash script with Task Scheduler here:

https://dev.to/ironfroggy/wsl-tips-starting-linux-background-services-on-windows-login-3o98

and

https://www.illuminiastudios.com/dev-diaries/ssh-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux/